# How to activate a NVIDIA GT218M [GeForce G210M] on an old ASUS laptop?

Tags: debian, nvidia

I am following this debian how-to:
https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers

but after many attempts, I still can't manage to get the GPU up and running. every time I reboot after finishing a configuration, I get no log-in screen and must delete the configuration over `tty`.

this is my most recent (and IMHO most polished) `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf`

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "AUO"
    ModelName      "AUO LCD Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
EndSection
```

if I have some mistakes, please correct :)

I also tried the Optimus approach:
https://wiki.debian.org/NVIDIA%20Optimus
given that I have this:

```
$ lspci -nn | egrep -i "3d|display|vga"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a42] (rev 07)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce G210M] [10de:0a74] (rev a2)
```

i tried it anyway, eventhough the `GT218M [GeForce G210M] [10de:0a74] (rev a2)` is not listed by NVIDIA (https://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/optimus/supported-gpus), this laptop does have 2 GPU (Intel+Nvidia)....

---

Some hardware info:

```
# hwinfo --monitor
23: None 00.0: 10002 LCD Monitor                                
  [Created at monitor.125]
  Unique ID: rdCR.GL1oUQj26t0
  Parent ID: _Znp.VGg1kf4in3D
  Hardware Class: monitor
  Model: "AUO LCD Monitor"
  Vendor: AUO "AUO"
  Device: eisa 0x30ec 
  Resolution: 1366x768@60Hz
  Size: 344x193 mm
  Year of Manufacture: 2009
  Week of Manufacture: 1
  Detailed Timings #0:
     Resolution: 1366x768
     Horizontal: 1366 1414 1446 1469 (+48 +80 +103) -hsync
       Vertical:  768  771  777  794 (+3 +9 +26) -vsync
    Frequencies: 70.00 MHz, 47.65 kHz, 60.01 Hz
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #21 (VGA compatible controller)
```

---

The NVIDIA-related packages I have installed:

```
# apt search nvidia | grep -a nstalliert

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

firmware-misc-nonfree/stable,now 20190114-2 all  [installiert]
glx-alternative-nvidia/stable,now 1.0.0 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libegl1-nvidia-legacy-340xx/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libgl1-nvidia-legacy-340xx-glx/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libgles1-nvidia-legacy-340xx/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libgles2-nvidia-legacy-340xx/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libnvidia-legacy-340xx-cfg1/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libnvidia-legacy-340xx-eglcore/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libnvidia-legacy-340xx-glcore/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libnvidia-legacy-340xx-ml1/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libvdpau1/stable,now 1.1.1-10 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-detect/stable,now 418.113-1 amd64  [installiert]
nvidia-installer-cleanup/stable,now 20151021+9 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-kernel-common/stable,now 20151021+9 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-legacy-340xx-alternative/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [installiert]
nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver-bin/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver-libs/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-legacy-340xx-kernel-dkms/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-legacy-340xx-kernel-support/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-modprobe/stable,now 418.56-1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-persistenced/stable,now 418.56-1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-settings-legacy-340xx/stable,now 340.108-1~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
nvidia-support/stable,now 20151021+9 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
vdpau-driver-all/stable,now 1.1.1-10 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/stable,now 1:1.0.16-1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-legacy-340xx/stable,now 340.108-3~deb10u1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's outdated answer but as is the GPUs architecture itself. You've got hybrid switchable nvidia technology. (A predecessor, "prototype" of Optimus technology).

Before the Optimus there were a series of notebooks that had "Switchable Hybrid Power" NVIDIA gpus. It worked more rough. It doesn't have "stand-by power mode" which activates discrete GPU on demand. There could be only one GPU working at once. The driver for both (Intel&Geforce) was provided by NVIDIA to OEM manufactuers. Example: UL50Vg had only one certificated drivers (the one which is on ASUS website) because every notebook with this tech had unique solutions.

When you'll check G210M on the NVIDIA driver download page you will see in the "Additional information" tab the 1st exception: "Notebooks supporting Hybrid Power technology are not supported (NVIDIA Optimus technology is supported)."

More info:
https://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/27115-latest-official-drivers-for-hybridswitchable-graphics-optimus/

https://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/26409-hybrid-graphics-master-set-drivers/#comments

#edit answer
@scjorge
I already spent some time on researching the case (G210M switchable) on both Windows & Linux platforms and the most suitable answer is no. But the fact you're running Linux makes the 4500MHD more efficient and its power should be enought for standard web-related work. I reccomend using h264ify addon for browser which makes youtube videos less stutter

If you'll look deeper into the problem you'll find some old posts dated back 2009/2010 on linux sites regarding this. The only working solution for ASUS UL50 series was to manual installing nvidia driver, setting up (to get blank screen after restart) and then switch HDD mode from AHCI to IDE (the limitatiation of Hybrid was that 2000/XP didn't supported it back then and IDE mode forced one of GPU to be the "one"). Even back then using IDE was considered unwise.

There was never official linux drivers released for NVIDIA Hybrid. In addition to this NVIDIA 340 (the last pre-Fermi drivers) is deprecated and is not working with newer kernels.

I ended up with Windows 7 (+ESU bypass) + official NVIDIA driver dated August 2009 (the initial one - the only one ever released) + gpedit rule to force dedicated PowerPlan (Power4Hybrid Perfomance) which makes the G210M work as default GPU

Comment: thanx for the input! but... does this means I can get the NVIDIA GPU running on my Debian? I am hoping this will increase performance a lot, or am I expecting too much?

Comment: @scjorge - answered in original post. I'm new on stackexchange and don't know if you'd be notified about edit

Comment: I was notified about your comment, not the edit. the notification of the edit was a little bar above the answer (I kept this window open, hoping for the best)

Comment: WOW! this is some great input!! and damn closed Hardware / closed Dirvers! And yes, the intel GPU is good enough. I just wanted to have the freedom to use all the hardware and may be learn some GPU-computing... that will have to wait